# validation with RadioButton

Tags: c#, radio-button, panel, tablelayoutpanel

I have 10 RadioButton inside a panel.

I have 10 panels inside a tableLayoutPanel, Each one in different column.

How can i move between the columns and validate that in each column there is a selected radioButton?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experiences with the `TableLayoutPanel`, but you could try this:

```
bool allValid = true;
for(int c = 0; c < panel.ColumnCount; c++)
{
    var colRadios = panel.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>() 
        .Where(rb => panel.GetColumn(rb) == c);
    bool colValid = colRadios.Any(rb => rb.Checked);
    if(!colValid)
    {
        allValid = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

(`panel` is the `TableLayoutPanel`)